# Proper way to manage children and navigate between children in a custom UIViewController container?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have always used standard `UIKit` `UIViewController` containers, like `UIPageViewController`, for my container needs, but I want to take a shot at creating a custom container. But there are some specific things I'm uncertain of. And this would be completely programmatic without a storyboard (therefore, without segue).

1. I want the container to house (for the sake of this example) 4 `UIViewController`'s that will be the 4 main sections of the UI. And within each section there will be a `UINavigationController` to handle the stack within its section. Therefore, these 4 `UIViewController`'s should be permanently added as children to the container (and never removed), correct? Reasoning: so that the user doesn't lose his/her place in a navigation stack when leaving and returning to that section.
2. I want to implement custom animation transitions between these 4 view controllers that will use pan gestures to drag them in and out of view. In the past, with `UINavigationController`, for example, a custom animation object would effectively override `pushViewController()`, but what would I be effectively overriding here?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to Apple, as I understand it, a view controller can either be pushed or "presented". I say "presented" because "presented" includes "present" (which I think is what confuses people), which brings in a `UIViewController` modally, while "show", which is also included under the "presented" umbrella, does not bring in a `UIViewController` modally, it works in some way like `push()` except that its not in a navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Therefore, these 4 `UIViewController`'s should be permanently added as children to the container (and never removed), correct?

As a minor refinement, you might load them in a just-in-time manner, loading them only when you'll actually need them. This avoids any potential delays resulting from loading many view controllers that might not yet be visible (if ever). But, sure, once loaded, you might keep them in memory. This is a pattern employed by Apple's own container view controllers.

> ... `show` ... does not bring in a `UIViewController` modally, it works in some way like `push()` except that it's not in a navigation stack.

The `show` method will navigate the view controller hierarchy, determine in which context it finds itself and will transition as accordingly. If you're within a navigation controller or split view controller, it will perform the appropriate transition. But if you're not within one of those controllers, it *will* perform a modal presentation. See the [`show` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621377-show).

> I want to implement custom animation transitions between these 4 view controllers that will use pan gestures to drag them in and out of view...

I'd suggest referring to [Custom Container View Controller Transitions](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/), which outlines how they use the [custom transition](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/) pattern in conjunction with your own [view controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/102/).

If that becomes too unwieldy, you might just go "old school" and just use gestures to animate views for the contained view controllers in and and out, doing all of the appropriate view controller containment related calls. It's not as elegant, but I suspect this might be easier.

---

If you do this manually (much easier), the only trick is to make sure you do the appropriate appearance and view controller containment calls. So, in the below example, we start with one of the four child view controllers added as a child of the container view controller, and this shows how to replace that child with another child view controller with a gesture. This keeps the view controller hierarchy in sync with the view hierarchy and makes sure that the children get their appropriate appearance methods called:

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass
import os.log

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy private var swipeFromRight: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer = {
        let swipe = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipeFromRight(_:)))
        swipe.edges = .right
        return swipe
    }()

    private var nextChildController: UIViewController?
    private var currentChildController: UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeFromRight)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipeFromRight(_ gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        let percent = -gesture.translation(in: gesture.view).x / gesture.view!.bounds.width

        if gesture.state == .began {
            os_log("starting gesture", type: .debug)

            guard let next = nextViewController() else {
                gesture.state = .cancelled
                return
            }

            currentChildController = childViewControllers.first!
            nextChildController = next
            startAppearance(next, replacing: currentChildController!, in: currentChildController!.view.superview)

            // prepare for gesture driven animation

            next.view.frame = currentChildController!.view.frame
            next.view.transform = .init(translationX: next.view.frame.width, y: 0)
        } else if gesture.state == .changed {
            // update animation based upon progress percent

            nextChildController!.view.transform = .init(translationX: nextChildController!.view.frame.width * (1 - percent), y: 0)
        } else if gesture.state == .ended {
            // figure out whether we should finish the animation (if not, we'll reverse it)

            let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: gesture.view).x
            let shouldFinish = velocity < 0 || (velocity == 0 && percent > 0.5)

            os_log("finishing gesture: shouldFinish=%@", type: .debug, shouldFinish ? "true" : "false")

            let next = nextChildController!
            let previous = self.currentChildController!

            if shouldFinish {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    next.view.transform = .identity
                }, completion: { finished in
                    self.endAppearance(next, replacing: previous)
                })
            } else {
                beginCancelAppearance(next, replacing: previous)

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    next.view.transform = .init(translationX: next.view.frame.width, y: 0)
                }, completion: { finished in
                    self.endCancelAppearance(next, replacing: previous)

                    next.view.transform = .identity
                })
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Child appearance/containment helpers

    private func startAppearance(_ appearingController: UIViewController, replacing disappearingController: UIViewController, in view: UIView? = nil) {
        appearingController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)

        addChildViewController(appearingController)
        view?.addSubview(appearingController.view)

        disappearingController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        disappearingController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)
    }

    private func beginCancelAppearance(_ appearingController: UIViewController, replacing disappearingController: UIViewController) {
        appearingController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        appearingController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)

        disappearingController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        disappearingController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
    }

    private func endCancelAppearance(_ appearingController: UIViewController, replacing disappearingController: UIViewController) {
        appearingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        appearingController.removeFromParentViewController()
        appearingController.endAppearanceTransition()

        disappearingController.endAppearanceTransition()
    }

    private func endAppearance(_ appearingController: UIViewController, replacing disappearingController: UIViewController) {
        appearingController.endAppearanceTransition()
        appearingController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        disappearingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        disappearingController.removeFromParentViewController()
        disappearingController.endAppearanceTransition()
    }

    // MARK: Next/Previous child helpers

    private func nextViewController() -> UIViewController? { ... }

    private func previousViewController() -> UIViewController? { ... }

}
```

Clearly, replace the animation with whatever animation you want. And, obviously, vend your view controllers however appropriate for your app. But it illustrates the nature of the gesture, appearance, and containment calls that need to be done.

Comment: That Custom Container View Controller Transitions link you posted is a tremendous resource. The old school approach you suggested is something I was curious about--do I even "need" present() or show() or any pre-made transition methods? I can just make a tab bar of my own (if I wanted one) that adds and removes the children views on touch events using .addSubView() and .removeFromSuperView(). And then, if I understand you correctly, use pan gesture recognizers to animate these custom methods in the places we want to add gesture-driven navigation?

Comment: If you go “old school”, no `show`/`present` is needed. Just the add/remove of the subviews and call the associated containment API. And drive this from your own gesture recognizers.

Comment: If the container is custom and pre-built transition methods like show, push, or present are not used, is there a way to hook up an animation object (like one that conforms to UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol) to the custom container using a transitioning delegate (the way one would normally override transitions)? From all that I've read in Apple documentation, these transitioning delegates appear to require use of methods like present or push.

Comment: Just saw your latest edit and code, parsing through it now.

Comment: @sconewolf - It doesn't have to be show/push/present. Look at tab bar controller or collection views, both examples where you use animation controllers in different ways. But Apple hasn't (yet) designed the scaffolding to just vend an animation controller for view controller containment, so you're doing a lot of stuff to make it work, diminishing the elegance of the pattern, IMHO.

Comment: I now see what you mean about losing elegance. How do you suspect an app like Snapchat accomplishes their main UI? It's so custom heavy, I assumed it was a custom, ground up approach. Or do you suspect they just placed things into premade containers and overrid everything?

Comment: I have no idea how they did what they did. But there's nothing here that requires or suggests that they used `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` vs other techniques.